# Why are they integrating from 1 to x?

Tags: differential

so I have a Bernoulli equation here, and I'm not sure why they are integrating from 1 to x. I understand that the initial condition is when x = 1, y = 1, but why are they integrating from 1 to x? They don't make a clear explanation, and I don't even know what to do with the initial condition at this point.

[image: Click for image here]

Comment: Where did you see an integral from $1$ to $x$? It is not shown on your screenshot.

Comment: So you are given initial conditions at $x=1$, and are looking for the value of the unknown function $y$ at argument $x$, and you're wondering why they're integrating from $1$ to $x$ (instead from $-\ln\pi$ to $x+e$, say), did I get that right?